# Detect and Disable Extension Modification to Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Lately I have installed some extensions from chromium store and saw some strange thing!. When I google something some modification to google shown on google result page. after I searched I found out that extension are causing this changes.

For example you can see 3 links in grey area that were added by a extension:
[image]

when I stay on those links it shows a link to searchgist.com like this:
http://g.searchgist.com/redir/ad/66aee535825aee62b99a19c7a0fe4a89

I had other modification that could be disable by clicking from target site. but not this one.

**Now I want to know which extentions are doing these modification and how to disable them?**

---

**System Information:**

Debian 7.2 64bit with gnome-shell 3.4

Chromium Version 30.0.1599.101 Debian 7.2 (227552)

*List of my extensions:* (*copied from my chrome://extensions/*)

*most of them are disable but problem resists.*

```
Advanced REST client 3.1.6
The web developers helper program to create and test custom HTTP requests. Permissions Visit website
ID: hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

Chrome Sniffer 0.3.1
Detect web applications and javascript libraries run on browsing website. Permissions Visit website
ID: homgcnaoacgigpkkljjjekpignblkeae

Dimensions 3.0
Easily test responsive websites, even offline. Permissions Visit website
ID: hdmihohhdcbejdkidbfijmfehjbnmifk

Measure Ruler 1.0
Measure ruler displays pixel dimensions and positioning. You can measure elements on any webpage. Permissions Visit website
ID: eldpakmnpncgomjohfedkmcbanhjbmcn

PageXray 1.25.3
This tool will show you the technologies used on any page. Permissions Visit website
ID: aedmpdookgbneegaeajpoldpnpfbpmlb

Postman - REST Client 0.8.4.3
Permissions Visit website
ID: fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm

Progress Bar Timer 1.71
Make general purpose trackers: progress bars that count time, dates, and anything you want. Permissions Visit website
ID: lmnlbapfmmoaehepmgbkgfcgpddlhbko

REST Console 4.0.2
REST Console is an HTTP Request Visualizer and Constructor tool, helps developers build, debug and test RESTful APIs. Permissions Visit website
ID: cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn

TypingClub 6.0
Permissions Visit website
ID: obdbgibnhfcjmmpfijkpcihjieedpfah

Allow in incognito
 Options

Wappalyzer 2.26
Identifies software on the web Permissions Visit website
ID: gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg
Inspect views: background.html

Allow in incognito
 Options

Web Developer 0.4.4
Adds a toolbar button with various web developer tools. The official port of the Web Developer extension for Firefox. Permissions Visit website
ID: bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm
Inspect views: background/background.html

Allow in incognito
   Allow access to file URLs Options

World Clocks 5.0
Interactive analog and digital clocks with times from over 400 cities in the world Permissions Visit website
ID: pjgoijhajhaahklokegbfnohialajpej

Allow in incognito
```

**UDPATE:**

A simple solution as suggested [here](http://assortmentofsites.com/remove-double-underlined-green-advertising-links/) and in comments is to disable all the plugins and enable them one by one and detect the culprit one. But it's not a good solution and the previous to the last one (which is stop using chrome!). There should be a way to know this before installing a extension and detect it after installation.

There is also a chance of having a malware! as it's in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/253996/are-google-chromes-in-text-ads-from-malware) .

And a solution for windows users seems to be [here](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-text-enhance-virus/) for one of the extension problem which I had before and not now.

Firefox has a solution with [adblock plugin](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/860638).

Comment: If you disable ALL your extensions does the problem persist?

Comment: Have you tried the proven process of elimination.  Your search results are unlikely being modified by an extension but instead by a proxy.  Can you go back and spell extension right please?

Comment: Google normally adds a few paid results in a gray box at the top of the result list for certain queries. How did you determine that it was the extensions that are causing that?

Comment: `Can you go back and spell extension right please?`   You realize that anyone can edit posts to improve them right? If it bothers you that much (or makes it too difficult to understand what is being asked), then you can always fix it yourself.

Comment: I fix my typo. thanks to you. and as Synetech said anyone could edit it too. I disabled all the plugins and the greybox disappeared. it's not a proxy problem because I don't have this problem with firefox. I relized this is an extenstion problem becasue I had another problem with another extension before (green linked words) and google result told me that's because of extensions. I don't like to disable my plugins. I want to control them. they shouldn't do this kinda things without asking users. it's discourteous.

Answer (score 0):

I started seeing searchgist.com ads on my Google searches a few days ago.

I turned off extensions one at a time and identified 'Tweet This Page' as the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I started seeing searchgist.com ads on many websites. It is infuriating. 
I was using Chrome.

But was able to remove this myself....a huge accomplishment.

Click on the three bars in the top right corner that allow you to "Customize and Control Google Chrome."
    Scroll down to TOOLS.
    Hoover to see EXTENSIONS.
       The extension that was allowing these pesky, and spammy links to searchgist.com ads was labeled as: "Social Privacy"  (how ironic.)

I unclicked the little box that said "Enable", and the pesky, spammy links are gone.
Hurray.
Harriete